# How to get a value from DataStore preferences, as Flow, within viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

i have a situation that I get resolved with SharedPreferences.
But now I'm migrating to kotlin and DataStore.

I faced this problem.

I have a String value stored in shared preferences, among other key-value pairs.
This String is an URL, to use in baseUrl parameter on a Retrofit call.

My problem is what's the correct way to retrieve the value, when I'm running in a ViewModel, of a Fragment.

This is part of my code:

```
@Singleton
class PreferencesManager @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    anioDao: AnioDao
) {

   val baseUrlFlow = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences: ", exception)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map {
            it[PreferencesKeys.BASER_URL] ?: "http://192.168.2.109:1337"
        }

}
```

then in ViewModel class

```
class EnsayosViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val ensayoRepository: EnsayoRepository,
    private val anioRepository: AnioRepository,
    private val localidadRepository: LocalidadRepository,
    private val epocaRepository: EpocaRepository,
    private val preferencesManager: PreferencesManager,
    private val agrotrackerApi: AgrotrackerApi,
    @Assisted private val state: SavedStateHandle

) :
    ViewModel() {

...

//Base Url
val baseUrlFlow = preferencesManager.baseUrlFlow
private val _baseUrl = MutableLiveData<String>()
private fun getBaseUrl() {

    viewModelScope.launch {
        baseUrlFlow.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect{
            _baseUrl.value = it
        }
    }
}

  ...

fun fetchEsayosFromAT() {

 //This is where I want to get value of the base_url key.

}
```

But it seems to be very complex, for a simple task...

What I'm missing? I'm really lost.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

One method of getting the shared preferences data is to transform Flow to LiveData. It works fine, but it is likely to be replaced with StateFlow/SharedFlow as a preferred method.

1. create a method in the Preference repository returning Flow

   ```
   override fun getBaseUrlPreferencesFlow(): Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data
   .catch { exception ->
       if (exception is IOException) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences: ", exception)
           emit(emptyPreferences())
       } else {
           throw exception
       }
   }
   .map { pref ->
      it[PreferencesKeys.BASER_URL] ?: "http://192.168.2.109:1337"
   }
   ```
2. In your ViewModel init the LiveData as shown below (you can access this from ViewModel or Fragment)

   ```
   val baseUrlLiveData: LiveData<String> = 
   yourInjectedRepository.getBaseUrlPreferencesFlow().asLiveData()
   ```
3. (Optional) in ViewModel - add helper method to process the base url

   ```
   private fun processUrl(): String {
     viewModelScope.launch {
          // base url http://192.168.2.109:1337
          val url = baseUrlLiveData.value 
       }         
   }
   ```

Comment: Your optional , helper method doesn't return result back, because launch does not return anything. It should be used withContext or async Instead of it to return the result of the coroutine.

Comment: That's why it is called "processUrl", not e.g "getUrl" with an intention to do something with the URL, not returning.